# Tkinter GUI not closing even though root is destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a check button GUI as shown below where the user can only choose one box, which is why both checkbuttons are refer to v1 with different onvalues:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

r = tkinter.Tk()
v1 = IntVar()
ch = []
ch.append(Checkbutton(r, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='Yes', variable=v1))
ch.append(Checkbutton(r, onvalue=2, offvalue=0, text='No', variable=v1))
ch[0].pack()
ch[1].pack()


def set_default():
    if v1 == 1:
        r.destroy()
    elif v1 == 2:
        r.destroy()

def_but2 = Button(r, text='Finish', command=set_default)
def_but2.pack(side="bottom")
r.mainloop()
```

Even though I destroy the object with r.destroy() when either object is chosen so that the window closes when the 'Finish' Button is clicked, the GUI does not close. Any ideas why that is the case?

Comment: Have you verified that `v1` is what you assume it is. I think you'll be surprised at what it is.  Try adding `print(v1)` in `set_default`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v1` is an `IntVar`, so its value should be retrieved via `v1.get()`:

```py
def set_default():
    val = v1.get()
    if val == 1:
        r.destroy()
    elif val == 2:
        r.destroy()
```

Note: It is better to use `Radiobutton` instead of `Checkbutton` for your case.

Comment: Thanks! Works out fine